# AR Overlay Accuracy in Google Project Tango

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I am experimenting with overlaying augmented reality objects over a pass-through image from the rear camera in Unity.

Has anyone experimented with overlaying objects with accurate tracking?  I've tweaked the movement scale to get somewhat decent results but rotation is still not accurate and drift is a big issue.

Comment: Do you mean using tango pose information to move the virtual object with respect to real world motion ?

Comment: Did you apply the camera extrinsic to the pose transformations? In general, changing moving scale is a bad idea in AR apps.

Comment: @MarkMullin exactly.  I assumed I could drop objects in to the Unity scene that corresponded to the real-world scene and the camera movements would mirror real-world movements so the experience would mesh.  Unfortunately the camera movements do not mirror real-world movements; it seems like rotation is scaled down but translation is fairly accurate.

Comment: I'm not seeing a uniform scale effect, but certainly am seeing drift - if you check out the movie I put up on the G+ Tango page you'll see I can get pretty good angular resolution if I cherry pick the data - yeah, that does put me in Mr. Tufte's rogues archive, but what the hell -  but DON'T mess with the rotation scale -  a handy trick with initial intake data is to only select stable poses, i.e. poses where there is a small positional or rotational delta with the previous pose

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with the augmented reality sample that ships with the latest tango.  in my experience it does work the way you speculated where if you add items to the unity scene they are synced to motion detected by the device.

I believe the tracking and syncing function have improved since you asked this question originally because I've noticed an improvement since I got my tango devkit a month or so ago.  there was an update a week or so later, with an immediate improvement.

I have found that some scenes track better than others, it seems to help for there to be additional scenery for it to track.  in my workspace, a fairly cluttered apartment, it tracks well but in the neighboring identical apartment unit which is currently vacant and empty, it does not track as well.  that could also be a product of the blinds hanging up in my unit that are not hanging up in the vacant unit, filtering out additional infrared.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experimenting with placing 3D objects over the real time input from the Tango color camera.

One problem here is that the hardware color camera 'point' in a (strange) direction. I wasn't able to get the direction vector from the api until now. Your virtual camera for rendering the scene needs this rotation to render 3D objects properly.

There are augmented reality examples of Tango's Unity plugin:
https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-simple-ar

They solve this problem with a matrix that rotates the 3d camera.

It can be found in the Unity script "TangoARPoseController" (C#) that, when attached to a unity camera, rotates it so that it looks at the scene in the right direction. The matrix is obtained in the method "SetCameraExtrinsics" of that script.

Unfortunately, when I apply the matrix to my unity scene it does not produce a perfect overlay (actually it's quiet bad). But I have other sources of position input which may be the problem here.

However, until now I'm not sure if the matrix used in the examples is good enough for accurate ar overlays. Maybe it is just suitable for demonstration purposes. But it should be a good starting point for further investigation.

Answer (score -1):

Are we talking about displaying the 'webcam' in the background as opposed to a skybox ?

Take a look at my GhostHunter repo. It includes a shader and a script for displaying the rear facing camera 'behind' the gameplay objects (like the skybox). It should be useable with Tango and it is better than the 'display on a mesh' technique I`ve seen others used.

https://github.com/NVentimiglia/Augmented-Reality-Ghost-Hunter